# Casting expected value of a generic type

Tags: c#

Surely, due to my limited knowledge in C# I believe there must be more efficient, cleaner way to dot this?

```
  public void Set(object nValue)
  {
      if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
          this.private_value = (T) (object) Convert.ToBoolean((string)nValue);
  }
```

where T is a value type for private_value. Usually bool or int.

Is there a better way to achieve this efficiently?

Comment: It seems more a design issue with your class than a C# syntax issue.

Comment: Yes there may be a better way but you have to tell us what you want to do, not how  you are doing. At a first glance from the code you have shown, generics may be an option.

Comment: When there are type tests in a generic class, it is a very strong indicator that generics are being misapplied.

Comment: You've just had three SO users with a combined rep of nearly 150,000 tell you that you should look at your class design. :-)

Comment: I understand that without much context that's what people believe is the best answer, but due to the nature of my design (runtime script virtual machine and instances created via Reflection) this was best I could get. I found a fix. Thank you. I appreciate your opinions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead:

```
this.private_value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(nValue, typeof(T));
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/dcW9It)